# EJS include statement forces html partial content into the body tag

Tags: html, ejs

I'm having troubles with EJS forcing the content of an included ejs partial element into the body tag.

index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </body>

    <footer>
        <%- include("../partials/footer") %>
    </footer>
</html>
```

partials/footer.ejs

```html
<div>
    <h3>Legal</h3>
    <a href="/legal/terms">Terms of Service</a>
</div>
```

Although the result of this is the footer being inside of the body tag as you can see from the inspect page tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [how browsers parse HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing). It has nothing to do with EJS.

The *footer* element is **not allowed** to be a child of the *html*  element (which has a content model saying that it must contain exactly [A *head* element followed by a *body* element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element)) so, to recover from your error, the browser moves the *footer* inside the *body* element where it is allowed.

You might be confusing the [*body* element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) for the [*main* element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main).